# How can i convert PHP string to array structure below

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can i convert PHP string to array structure below

```
$_country = "IN:India,UK:United Kingdom,AU:Australia";

$_country = array(
'IN' => 'India',
'UK' => 'United Kingdom',
'AU' => 'Australia'
);
```

Comment: [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Twice

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something similar to this - explode to find the pairs and then split each pair into param/value

```
$_country = "IN:India,UK:United Kingdom,AU:Australia";
$tmp=explode(',', $_country);
$pairs=[];
foreach($tmp as $pair){
    list($param,$value)=explode(':',$pair);
    $pairs[$param]=$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it can be done with [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) functions:

```
<?php

$_country = "IN:India,UK:United Kingdom,AU:Australia";
$normalizedStr = str_replace([',', ':'], ['&', '='], $_country);

parse_str($normalizedStr, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Working example is [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea559c5bf505b3f6470d383205904c848ea97141).

Comment: Yes - this is working but previous code to solved my issue. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a solution. **Hope this will help**

```
$_country = "IN:India,UK:United Kingdom,AU:Australia";
$code=explode(',',$_country);
for($i=0;$i<=count($code)-1;$i++){
    $ar[]=explode(':', $code[$i]);

}
print_r($ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun xmas day one-liners:

```
<?php
$str = "IN:India,UK:United Kingdom,AU:Australia";

$result = 
    array_column(
        array_chunk(
            str_getcsv(
                str_replace(':', ',', $str)
            ),
            2
        ),
        1,
        0
    );
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'IN' => 'India',
    'UK' => 'United Kingdom',
    'AU' => 'Australia',
  )
```

Or a foreach one-liner:

```
foreach(str_getcsv($str) as $pair)
    $result[($split = str_getcsv($pair, ':'))[0]] = $split[1];
```

Or the double explode:

```
$result =
    array_column(
        array_map(
            function($v) {
                return explode(':', $v);
            },
            explode(',', $str)
        ),
        1,
        0
    );
```

Or the parse_str one:

```
parse_str(
    strtr(
        $str,
        [
            ',' => '&',
            ':' => '='
        ]
    ),
    $result
);
```